# Debian 8 - TCP Overflows / TCP Drops

Tags: debian, linux-networking, tcp, connection, sysctl

I have recently installed netdata on my Debian 8 server (monitoring software) and afetr installing my Debian 8 server is reporting the below two alerts constantly.

- 1m ipv4 tcp listen overflows = 37 overflows
- 1m ipv4 tcp listen drops = 3 drops

I was wondering if anyone could suggest any settings to reduce/stop these errors, maybe some sysctl.conf settings will correct this?

Currenty I have attempted to reduce with the below sysctl.conf settings (with no luck).

net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 524288

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_max_orphans = 65535

net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 3

net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1

net.core.somaxconn = 65535

net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

net.ipv4.tcp_abort_on_overflow=0

Comment: you need to check the listen backlog in you application man listen and resize net.core.somaxconn

Comment: I have already set the net.core.somaxconn = 65535 to the highest setting?

Comment: what application are you using? because the application needs to set the backlog option when calling listen syscall

Comment: Hmmm I assumed it was Debian and not the application, anyway I'm using https://github.com/UNOMP/unified-node-open-mining-portal.